# magento2 - before place order

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, magento2

I'm struggling to override or get in the middle of some checkout action scripts, for example the place-order method of app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/review.js

I can see there is a "beforePlaceOrder" variable in there but I'm unsure how to subscribe my own method there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to overwrite a function instead a class method (I used to overwrite Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order).

requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order': {
                'My_Module/js/action/place-order': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

place-order.js

```
define(['mage/utils/wrapper'], function (wrapper) {
    'use strict';

    return function (placeOrderAction) {
        return wrapper.wrap(placeOrderAction, function (originalAction, paymentData, redirectOnSuccess) {
            // my own code here
            return originalAction(paymentData, redirectOnSuccess);
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The code you described is not in magento 2 anymore. Checkout has been modified.

You can substitute any action (and any requireJs component) using requireJs *map* configuration (http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map) in magento requireJs config files.

Interception (or mixins) feature is not yet implemented for JS) but it's in development right now and will be delivered pretty soon.