# Magento2 checkout: add required checkbox, required validation not working

Tags: magento2, checkout, validation

I am trying to add a required checkbox to the checkout summary of magento2, above the submit order button. I have managed to place the checkbox, but the order can still be submitted even if the checkbox is not checked. I have tried everything / searched everywhere but cant seem to figure this one out.

Problem:

- Order can be submitted if checkbox is unchecked

Question:
How do I add a 'required' validation for the checkbox, comparable to the terms & conditions in the image below:
[image: checkout two boxes with and without required validation]

Thanks for the help!

**My code:** (note: might have allot of redundant 'required' attempts, some css classes are just for styling, even though they make no sense functionally)

**(1) app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <!-- Modifying an existing step-->
                                            <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="itemsAfter" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="productcheck" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">AquiveMedia_CustomCheckBoxesCheckout/js/view/productCheck</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                           <item name="nocancel" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">AquiveMedia_CustomCheckBoxesCheckout/js/view/productCheck</item>
                                                            </item>             
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>    
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**(2) app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/web/js/view/productCheck.js**

```
define(
    [
    'ko',
    'uiComponent'
    ],
    function (ko, Component) 
   {
    "use strict";
   
    return Component.extend({
    defaults: 
   {
    template: 'AquiveMedia_CustomCheckBoxesCheckout/nocancel'
    }
    });
    }
   );
```

**(3) app/code/vendorname/modulename/view/frontend/web/template/productcheck.html**

```
<div class="payment-method">
    <div class="fieldset checkout-agreements">
        <div class="field required checkout-agreement">
            <input type="checkbox" class="required required-entry label" name="nocancel" data-validate="{required:true}" data-bind="attr: {id: 'nocancel'}"/>
            <label class="label" data-bind="attr: {for: 'nocancel'}"><span data-bind="i18n: 'Custom checkbox 2'"></span></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/222416/validation-of-the-terms-and-conditions-custom-module

Comment: I am not really seeing how that link helps me. Could you explain?

Comment: check terms and condition validation. how Magento validate

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that Magento/knockout does not know *when* to validate your checkbox? I think what is missing here could be the requirejs-config which could help Magento/knockout understand in which step you would like the validation.

For instance, if you would like it validated just before the order is placed you could do the following: create a (view\frontend)requirejs-config.js with

```
var config = {
config: {
    mixins: {
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order': {
            'AquiveMedia_CustomCheckBoxesCheckout/js/model/no-cancel-mixin': true
        }
    }
}
};
```

So now you need a no-cancel-mixin where you validate your checkbox (or multiple checkboxes). Your no-cancel-mixin.js:

```
define([
   'jquery',
   'mage/utils/wrapper',
   'AquiveMedia_CustomCheckBoxesCheckout/js/model/no-cancel'
], function ($, wrapper, noCancel) {
  'use strict';

 return function (placeOrderAction) {

    return wrapper.wrap(placeOrderAction, function (originalAction, paymentData, messageContainer) {
        noCancel(paymentData); // so this is your function that you can use to validate things

        return originalAction(paymentData, messageContainer);
    });
};
});
```

Then of course you need the noCancel function:

```
define([
  'jquery'
 ], function ($) {
 'use strict';

var noCancel = window.getyourCheckboxhere;

/** Override default place order action and add agreement_ids to request */
return function (paymentData) {
    var someOtherVar;

    // do some validation here
    console.log('hello no-cancel');
    return false; // or true
   };
});
```

Now in your console you will find the "hello no-cancel" sentence. And you can play around with various validation methods.

I have used [magento2 - before place order](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73107/magento2-before-place-order) to create the above example. But you could also use the set payment information step:

```
'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-payment-information': {
            'Magento_CheckoutAgreements/js/model/set-payment-information-mixin': true
 }
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

simply disable the submit order button until unless they click on terms & conditions then unable it using js.

on page load disable it by css and on click checkbox enable it.